# Treat excel/csv file as file just considering rows, instead of rows and columns

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I need to get a specific row from an excel file, and to do so i am using pandas library, in python. Here it follows:

```
path = r"C:\Users\Utilizador\Desktop\vendas2017.xlsx"
dataframe = pd.read_excel(path)
print dataframe.ix[1]
### I'm getting this, in which the second row columns are the first row corresponding cells:
sales | meatMenu | fishMenu | vegetarianMenu ### very first row
323   |    1     |    0     |  0             ### second row


## I want to print something like (as a truly independent plain text, one row at a time), without any column concept associated:
sales | meatMenu | fishMenu | vegetarianMenu ### very first row
323   |    1     |    0     |  0             ### second row
friday| sunny    | Mild     | rainy          ### third row
1     |    0     |    1     |  0             ### fourth row
```

I just want the rows as plain text instead of indexing, as its corresponding columns, the very first line/row content cells. Do you know any workaround to perform such?

Much appreciated and an happy Easter!

Comment: Why is *printing* important to you? I'm sure there must be a good reason, but a one-sentence context would help. You can't have a dataframe without an index, so it seems you only care about the presentation and just happen to start with a dataframe.

Comment: @jpp nvm, I solved it. TL;DR i just needed to remove the headers. To do so, header=None, when calling read_excel() function. Thanks anyway :)